# Heroku : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/build/index.html'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

My directory :

[image]

I try depoly to my react project in Heroku.

But, it print error message.

It is 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/build/index.html'

My node.js server code

server/app.js:

```
import express from  'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import loader from './loader';

const app = express();

// server static file
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));

app.use('/', loader);

// exporting module
export default app;
```

server/loader.js :

```
...
export default (req, res) => {
const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html');

fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData)=>{
  if (err) {
    console.error('read error', err)
    return res.status(404).end()
  }
  const context = {}
  const markup = renderToString(
  <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
    <App/>
  </StaticRouter>
  )

  if (context.url) {
    redirect(301, context.url)
  } else {
    const Rendered = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}', markup)
    res.send(Rendered)
  }
})
```

I think I have no problems, but when I try to connect, I get a 'not found' page.

How can I fix the problem?

+edit:

My package.json:

```
...
"engines": {
  "node": "6.11.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.16.2",
"express": "^4.15.4",
"morgan": "^1.8.2",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-ga": "^2.2.0",
"react-router": "^4.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"react-scripts": "1.0.10",
"semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.12",
"semantic-ui-react": "^0.71.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server",
"start:server": "NODE_ENV=development babel-node server",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "mocha test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore": "^0.1.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.2",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"chai": "^4.1.1",
"mocha": "^3.5.0",
"mz": "^2.6.0",
"supertest": "^3.0.0",
"supertest-as-promised": "^4.0.2"
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please post your package.json and commands you used to deploy the app

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara Sorry, I edit to add Package.json.  
I command the 'git push heroku master' . That's it.

Comment: and I command the "heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false ."

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but https://zeit.co/now let you deploy node apps with one command. I started using it recently and save a lot of pain.

Comment: @CarlosC Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CI solution for building and pushing to heroku such as circleci or travisci. This is what I do so i'm sure to get a fresh build without errors.

Pushing the `build` folder to github is fine as well. I'm sure someone would disagree for some reason i'm not aware of but it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out.
It has ' build ' in my .gitignore file.

If so, build directory will also push in github, is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

sure you could generate and push the build folder, but I don't think it's the best way to build locally.
you could

1. use npm script such as 'heroku-postbuild' to handle build
   step when deploy(plz read
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support), so it will
   generate the build file on the server.
2. use CI to handle the test and build parts, but it's pretty complex
   and normally for large projects